# Make it to throw errors if no records found using .filter

Tags: python, django

When I search for a record which does not recorded in database, it return a null

```
In [15]: a = Article.objects.filter(title="hello")
In [16]: a
Out[16]: <QuerySet []>
```

This mean, it silence if I use try and except

```
arr = []
try:
    a = Article.objects.filter(title="strange title")
    arr.append(a)
except SyntaxError:
    print("typo, double check")
```

How to make it report error if no records qualified?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to collect the qualified records to a list @ThatBird

Comment: Alright so how does an empty list and raising errors are related?

Comment: If `a = Article.objects.filter(title="strange title")` line raises an exception, the next line `arr.append(a)` won't get executed even if you use `try except` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to use try and except block.

You can just check if results are not empty then don't do anything
example:

```
a = Article.objects.filter(title="hello") 
if a:
  print "do something"
else:
  print "record not found"
```